# I want to practice the usage of <dialog> tag inside the react environment. So I want to covert this HTML code into React code

Tags: html, reactjs

Here I use HTML only. If I use the `<dialog>` tag in HTML, It has a bunch of inbuild methods. Some of them are used here. But If I use modal.Show() and modal.Close() methods and more inside the React environment, It gives me errors.So Can anyone help me to convert this HTML code into react code? I need to keep all properties and attributes as it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
    <style>
      dialog::backdrop {
        background-color: rgb(108, 113, 111);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is H1 Tag</h1>
    <button data-open-modal>Open me</button>
    <dialog data-modal>
      <p close-modal>X</p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quaerat ipsa
        quod ipsum numquam officia, eveniet deleniti aspernatur quo accusamus
        distinctio eligendi necessitatibus commodi ipsam! Doloremque quod hic
        odio placeat aliquid. Ipsam esse cumque fugiat optio inventore, eligendi
        ex tempora ad adipisci accusamus exercitationem ratione itaque sapiente.
        Eveniet pariatur iusto rem soluta tenetur nemo enim qui adipisci
        dolorem? Ullam, quibusdam neque. Nisi necessitatibus repellat

        <button data-close-modal>Close me</button>
      </p>
      <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit" formmethod="dialog">Close me</button>
        <button type="submit">Submit me</button>
      </form>
    </dialog>

    <script>
      const openButton = document.querySelector("[data-open-modal]");
      const closeButton = document.querySelector("[data-close-modal]");
      const modal = document.querySelector("[data-modal]");

      openButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal.showModal();
      });
      closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal.close();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the entire react application environment, I would recommend to use next.js which uses react, super easy and complete.

Follow the step by step tutorial: https://nextjs.org/docs

Or see another frameworks also recommended by react: https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project#production-grade-react-frameworks

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response, Cristobal. I can convert this code into react code. But I can not use modal. Show() and modal. Close() methods. There are no such methods in react. Can you give any suggestions to take all the functionalities that i written in above code to the react code?

Comment: That it is becouse in react you have to use if statements to display one or other html element

Comment: I also recommend to check out this dialog component https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/